# How to add additional column CompanyName (Get-AzureADUser) in CSV output?

Tags: powershell

How to add additional column with CompanyName data from Get-AzureADUser cmdlet in CSV output? UserPrincipalName parameter is same and exists in both cmdlets.

```
    #Define country set where agencies are under support. Over time must be manually updated.
    $CountryList = ('SWEDEN', 'NORWAY')
    #Looping each country under support. Under interest are O365 enabled & licensed accounts.
    $DataSet = foreach ($Country in $CountryList)
    {
        Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -Country "$Country" | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true} | Select-Object Country, State, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, FirstName, LastName, Department, Title, MobilePhone, PhoneNumber, isLicensed
    } 
    $DataSet | Export-Csv C:\Users\unknown\Report.csv
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think you also need to use `Get-AzureADUser` in a loop using the UserPrincipalName you got from `Get-MsolUser` to obtain the `CompanyName` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished:

```
#Define path for result CSV.
$DataPath = "C:\Users\unknown\Report.csv"
#Define result hash table.
$Results = @() 
#Define country set where agencies are under support. Over time must be manually updated. 
$CountryList = ('SWEDEN', 'NORWAY') 
#Looping each country under support. Under interest are O365 enabled & licensed accounts. 
$DataSet = foreach ($Country in $CountryList) 
{ 
    Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -Country "$Country" | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true}
}  
#Looping each enabled, licensed UPN from supported country set to form subhash tables and write parameters to result hash table.
foreach ($UPN in $DataSet.UserPrincipalName) 
{ 
$DataSetAAD = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UPN
$DataSetMsol = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
    $Properties = @{
    CompanyName = $DataSetAAD.CompanyName 
    Country = $DataSetMsol.Country
    UserPrincipalName = $DataSetMsol.UserPrincipalName 
    DisplayName = $DataSetMsol.DisplayName 
    FirstName = $DataSetMsol.FirstName 
    LastName = $DataSetMsol.LastName 
    Department = $DataSetMsol.Department 
    Title = $DataSetMsol.Title
    MobilePhone = $DataSetMsol.MobilePhone 
    PhoneNumber = $DataSetMsol.PhoneNumber 
    isLicensed = $DataSetMsol.isLicensed
    }
$Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
} 
#Export result table to CSV 
$Results | Select-Object CompanyName,Country,UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,Department,Title,MobilePhone,PhoneNumber,isLicensed | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $DataPath
```